# How to call a function multiple times, pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, click

I am trying to build a multiple elements with tabbed content functionality. How can I use the same function with multiple elements declared in var?
E.g. to have cloned parent div.tabs element with similar content but different ids and area-labels; Don't mind the CSS ts just for snippet visuals

```js
        const tab = document.querySelector('.tabs');    
        const tabButtons = tab.querySelectorAll('[role="tab"]');
        const tabPanels = Array.from(tab.querySelectorAll('[role="tabpanel"]'));

        function tabClickHandler(e) {
            //Hide All Tabpane
            tabPanels.forEach(panel => {
                panel.hidden = 'true';
            });

            //Deselect Tab Button
            tabButtons.forEach( span => {
                span.setAttribute('aria-selected', 'false');
            });

            //Mark New Tab
            e.currentTarget.setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true');

            //Show New Tab
            const { id } = e.currentTarget;

            const currentTab = tabPanels.find(
                panel => panel.getAttribute('aria-labelledby') === id
            );

            currentTab.hidden = false;
        }

        tabButtons.forEach(span => {
            span.addEventListener('click', tabClickHandler);
        });
```

```css
    /* Tabs Styling */
    .tabs [role="tablist"] > h3 {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .tabs [role="tablist"] > h3[aria-selected="true"] {
        color: #4fcbf2;
    }
    .tabs [role="tabpanel"] p {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #eff1f2;
        padding: 1.8em 2.2em;
    }
    .wp-block-columns {
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 1.75em;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        gap: 1em;
    }
    .wp-block-columns {
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
    .wp-block-column {
        flex-basis: 0;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="tabs wp-block-columns">
<div class="wp-block-column" role="tablist" aria-label="contractors">
    <h3 class="has-normal-font-size" role="tab" aria-selected="true" id="contractors-1">Do you have a limited company that you want to use for international contracting but don't know how?</h3>
    <h3 class="has-normal-font-size" role="tab" aria-selected="false" id="contractors-2">Do you want to work abroad but are not satisfied with the retentions that</h3>
</div>
<div class="tabcontent wp-block-column">
    <div role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contractors-1"><p>Access Tax and Accounting is a firm of accountants that specialises in this fields</p></div>
    <div role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contractors-2" hidden=""><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus semper</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, maybe not the best way, but it works. I added a unique ID to each tabs container:

`<div id="tabs-1" class="tabs wp-block-columns"> ... </div>`

`<div id="tabs-2" class="tabs wp-block-columns"> ... </div>`

Created the list of elements using `getElementsByClassName` and placed my function and event listener in `for` loop with element list length as a condition. After all replaced class name `querySelector` with id name `.id` selected from elements list. Array item controlled by loop variable.

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('tabs').length) {
            
            var tabClass = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
            
            for (var i = 0; i < tabClass.length; i++) {
                
                const tab = document.querySelector('#' + tabClass[i].id);

                function tabClickHandler(e) { ... }             
                
                tabButtons.forEach(button => { ... });      
                
            }

}
```